# Windows unable to find the path for command although the same works on CMD manually but through batch file it does not work

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set maxInstances=6

rem Report start time
echo BatchStartTime=%date:~7,2%%date:~3,3%%date:~10,4% @ %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% > C:\Users\phare\Desktop\100MillionData\Batch_Logs\BatchStartTime_log.txt


rem Delete all cmd instance files
del cmdInstance?.txt 2>NUL

for /F "tokens=*" %%x in (C:\Users\phare\Desktop\100MillionData\Post.txt) do (
   rem Mimic commandline

   echo cmd  "cd Desktop\IncrementalBatchIndexing" ^> %%x 

   rem Perform command
   call :WaitForNextInstance

   echo This instance started at !time! > cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt 


  start "" "cmd /c call %%x & del cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt"




 echo/


)

rem Wait for all active instances end
call :WaitAllInstancesEnd

rem Report end time and terminate
echo BatchEndTime=%date:~7,2%%date:~3,3%%date:~10,4% @ %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% > C:\Users\phare\Desktop\100MillionData\Batch_Logs\BatchEndTimelog.txt

goto :EOF  

:WaitForNextInstance
rem Review active instances and get the first available one

for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxInstances%) do if not exist cmdInstance%%i.txt set "nextInstance=%%i" & exit /B

echo cmd /K "cd C:\Users\phare\Desktop\100MillionData" ^> 

rem Delay some time (10 seconds in this example) and repeat
rem ping -n 11 localhost >NUL 

goto WaitForNextInstance 


:WaitAllInstancesEnd
rem Check if any instance is still active
set "anyInstance="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxInstances%) do if exist cmdInstance%%i.txt set anyInstance=true
if not defined anyInstance exit /B 
rem Delay some time (10 seconds in this example) and repeat
rem rem ping -n 11 localhost >NUL

goto WaitAllInstancesEnd
```

Comment: Try ^@ in the command. & seperates commands on the same line. ^ quotes special characters.

Comment: If u mean adding ^ before @ then its not working..Please Help

Comment: Have you have used a variable called `path` or changed the path statement radically?

Comment: Nope I found the issue. Actually the issue is my batch program executes one command closes the command window then opens next window and executes the other command from the text file. The command that was causing the issue is  Start " "cmd /c call %%x"" but after removing cmd /c call my command in the text file is executing but only the first one executes and the remaining does not execute. Any suggestions..

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched.

Comment: Try not to use Start. Use call directly.

Comment: plesae find my code in the edit. If I remove start and the inverted commas then command gets executed but one at a time in one window only. If I keep Start and just remove the inverted commas then then commands get executed in different windows but the issue is if i am having 15 command in the input file then 15 cmd window opens its not limiting to 6. This code worked well for simple commands executing 6 commands on 6 cmd windows and as soon as any of the window is closed another window would replace it thereby keeping the no. of cmd to 6 at any point of time.

Comment: But with the new command i.e java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Users\phare\Desktop\100MillionData\cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Durl=https://solrwrite:solrwrite@lxv0894.allstate.com:8443/solr/collection1/updateparty -Dtype=text/csv -jar post.jar Data_0.csv if I keep the inverted comma in start i.e Start "" "cmd /c call %%x &del instance.txt" it fails to recognise the path itself but if I remove the inverted comma it recognises the path and executes,something needs to be escaped in this command I guess. The issue seems to be with https://solrwrite:solrwrite.....

Comment: Edit your question and add the details there.